# BuyItem method from Samsung Checkout SDK returns an error callback inside .NET application

Tags: .net, checkout, tizen, samsung

I'm having a problem with Samsung Checkout integration in out existing .NET TizenFX (TV) application.

I followed the instructions here: https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/tizen-net-tv/guides/samsung-checkout/implementing-the-purchase-process.html

First step where I request a product for sale goes through successfully. I get the product, parse its data and prepare all parameters to call the **BuyItem** method. Unfortunately the method returns an error callback, and no purchase GUI is shown in the application.

Error callback I get is:

```
 {
  "result": "FAIL",
  "optionalData": "{\n  \"OrderTotal\": \"7.45\",\n  \"OrderItemID\": \"myitemid\",\n  \"OrderTitle\": \"My Item Title\",\n  \"OrderCurrencyID\": \"USD\",\n  \"OrderCustomID\": \"123456789\"\n}"
 }
```

I also found that the error callback was returned somewhere in the process of preparing possible payments (according to stack trace):

```
Tizen.TV.Service.Billing.BillingPlugin.PaymentCallback()
```

Has anyone already integrated the Samsung checkout SDK and had similar problems?